# How do I save user specific quiz answers in django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am having the following Quiz model:-

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    quiz_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.quiz_name
```

Each Quiz model has a set of Questions and each Question has set of related possible answers. The question also has a correct answer field. Following are the models for questions and answers:-

Answer Model:-

```
class Answer_Options(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text
```

Question Model:-

```
class Quiz_Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='questions')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    possible_answers = models.ManyToManyField(Answer_Options)
    correct = models.ForeignKey(Answer_Options, related_name="correct", default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text
```

Now the problem that I am facing is that how can I save which user has selected which option? Is there a way to do so?

Comment: I would say create another table with, `user_id, question_id, answer_id, quiz_id`

Comment: Yes that would be a workaround but is there a way to do so with existing models itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with existing model. You need to create another model for the quiz answers and store the following fields there:

- option id
- user id

You don't need the question or quiz id here because you can get it through option id.

Assuming you are using the User model, here is a sample model code:

```
class QuizAnswer(models.Model):
    answer_option = models.ForeignKey(Answer_Options)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

By the way, your model names are not following the standards.

Comment: Is it possible in some way or another using model inheritance?

Comment: Since we have to check the correct answer with the selected answer if we save the answer along with the user then the check would fail

Answer (score 0):

i would go with

```
qs = Quiz.objects.all()
obj = qs.filter(name__istartswith="What is the answer to the universer an everything")
if answer == obj.correct:
    #he is right
    #maybe save to session
else:
    #wrong
```

Comment: I don't want to save just the answer. I want to save the user and his selected answer for that particular question.